# Get touch event on Paint object in android

Tags: android, android-canvas, ondraw

I'm drawing a circle using 7 paint objects as below on a canvas in my android app. same paint object can be used more than one time to draw this circle.

Now I want to display color name of touched paint object, when user touch on each color.

How can I do this ?

[image: Circle using paint objects]

Answer (score 0):

Use on Touch Event for the same like :

```
public class TouchImage extends ImageView {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Point point = new Point();

    public TouchImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, 10, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            point.x = event.getX();
            point.y = event.getY();
            invalidate();
        }
        return true;
    }

    class Point {
        float x, y;
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm not using `canvas.drawCircle()` to draw my circle. i'm using `canvas.drawArc()` for this. with the combination of 24 arcs, draw a one circle.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the positions for all color circles.
Inside onTouchEvent() you can compare the distance between each color circle and touch position with color circles radius.

If distance is less than radius (and maybe greater than min value, so only the colors are touchable and not the empty area inside circle) you could otbtain the angle and determine selected color this way.

```
 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        for (colorCircle c : allCircles) {
            float distance = sqrt ((event.getX() - c.getX())^2 +
                ((event.getY() - c.getY())^2);
            if (distance < c.getRadius()) {
                for (coloredPart cPart : c) {
                    if (event.getX() > (Math.cos(cPart.getMinAngle) * c.getRadius)
                        + c.getX() && 
                        event.getX() < (Math.cos(cPart.getMaxAngle) * c.getRadius)
                        + c.getX() && 
                        event.getY() > (Math.sin(cPart.getMinAngle) * c.getRadius)
                        + c.getY() && 
                        event.getY() < (Math.sin(cPart.getMaxAngle) * c.getRadius)
                        + c.getY() && ) {
                        // cPart was touched
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```